# How to playback audio to an image on hover?

Tags: html, css

So I am creating a Webflow website where I want to add several images that playback different audio clips when hovering.

Also, if possible to add a sliding effect displaying the remaining time left. Change the opacity to a slightly darker shade and return to normal as the slider goes from left to right like the time bar on YouTube but on the whole image.

Any suggestions, pointers, or resources that can guide me in the right direction will be much appreciated.

Comment: I imagine I would have to embed some custom code to make this happen.

Comment: requires js. What does this question has to do with a CSM or webflow? Please read the description of the tags more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `onMouseOver` attribute to trigger a certain audio file when hovering that element by using the `element.play()` command.

To pause the audio-file when not hovering you can use the `onMouseOut` attribute and combine it with the `element.pause()` command:

A timebar would require extensive scripting and be a second question. SO is the wrong plattform for that.

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200.jpg" 
     onMouseOver="document.getElementById('audio-1').play()" 
     onMouseOut="document.getElementById('audio-1').pause()">



<audio id="audio-1" src="https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3">
```